# "payee" key in paypalrestsdk in my Flask App is causing me trouble

Tags: flask, paypal

I am coding a simple test Flask App in which I'm trying to allow users to pay a certain PayPal account. To do this, I added a "payee" key in my "payment_data" dictionary with a value of the PayPal account's email address.

Here is my app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import paypalrestsdk

app = Flask(__name__)

paypalrestsdk.configure({
  "mode": "sandbox", # sandbox or live
  "client_id": "AY0xw74ZNbvbYuhq3SOWkJ_SxiR4bpJ_Il3z_Hk0lZZoRrKsIWE1UOBXmfYwyTV965AcGRjNS0eouLkO",
  "client_secret": "EDjD8TovplQDbb4VhmYpiGq3M8gLlMu0-sqSpcYkDncjAZG3sIJ3LsROC9cGjMbPIxFAjHNNYS4hqdYm" })

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/payment', methods=['POST'])
def payment():
    payment_data = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/payment/execute",
            "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/"
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
                "items": [{
                    "name": "testitem",
                    "sku": "12345",
                    "price": "500.00",
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "quantity": 1
                }]
            },
            "amount": {
                "total": "500.00",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
            "payee": "glolibros.business@gmail.com"  # Add the payee email here
        }]
    }

    payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment(payment_data)

    if payment.create():
        print('Payment Success!')
    else:
        print(payment.error)

    return jsonify({'paymentID': payment.id})

@app.route('/execute', methods=['POST'])
def execute():
    success = False

    payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(request.form['paymentID'])

    if payment.execute({'payer_id' : request.form['payerID']}):
        print('Execute success!')
        success = True
    else:
        print(payment.error)

    return jsonify({'success' : success})

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="paypal-button"></div>

    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

    <script>
        var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL  = '/payment';
        var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = '/execute';
    
        paypal.Button.render({
    
            env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'
    
            commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button
    
            payment: function() {
                return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL).then(function(data) {
                    return data.paymentID;
                });
            },
    
            onAuthorize: function(data) {
                return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, {
                    paymentID: data.paymentID,
                    payerID:   data.payerID
                }).then(function(res) {
    
                    console.log(res.success)
                });
            }
    
        }, '#paypal-button');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nevertheless, when I test the app and click the PayPal button displayed on my website, a PayPal window loads, to then disappear. This doesn't actually happen when I don't include the "payee" key in my dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The API call is failing and returning an error, hence nothing can open. Assuming you are returning the error, this can be observed in the browser's network tab.

The *reason* the API call is failing is the value of the `payee` key is invalid. It must contain a subkey such as `email`, as documented in the [v1/payments API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_create!path=transactions/payee&t=request).

---

The v1/payments API is obsolete (over 9 years old) and you should not be using it for any new integration. Integrate with v2/checkout/orders instead.

There is no PayPal-supported SDK for v2/checkout/orders; use direct HTTPS API calls to first obtain an access_token yourself using the client_id and secret.